# load data from multiple files

Tags: import, scilab

Can I ask for these two pieces of advice?

1. How to read all files named Pene_n.txt where n is a digit?
   I was attacked by these orders, but the fourth one, for some reason unknown to me, does not work :(
2. Is there a simple command how I could write new data for old data in that matrix (without header)?

My code:

```
numberOfFiles = size (listfiles("pene.txt"))
for i=1:1:numberOfFiles(1,1)
    //this 4 line is trouble :((
    Data = csvRead(("Pene_%d.txt",i),";",",","string")
end
```

Please does anyone how to do it?
By the way there I put whole file :) http://leteckaposta.cz/859703762

Comment: Please learn from my edit how to include code. You just have to copy/paster from the Scilab editor window.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely

1. missing the correct path with wildcard and correctly get length of string vector

```
numberOfFiles = size(listfiles("Pene_*.txt"),1)
```

2. missing `msprintf` before its arguments in the loop:

```
Data = csvRead(msprintf("Pene_%d.txt",i),";",",","string")
```

For your second question use `csvWrite` (see its help page with `help csvWrite`).